# What is 'No. of Trades' in NSE's 'Security-wise achieves' web page?

Tags: equities

Let's say we have a stock ABC trading in NSE (Nation stock exchange of India), let's assume only 10 shares get traded on a particular day (so, volume is 10). A person named 'X' sells 10 shares from his Demat account, a person 'Y' buys 5 shares and another person 'Z' buys 5... What is the 'No. of Trades' for this particular case? Is it 1 or 3?
https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm (Look into this website for more information...)